# form target="blank" takes forever to load the new page in Safari

Tags: forms, safari, target

In my code, I have this form tag:

```
<form target="_blank" method="POST">
```

Then afterwards I have my inputs then a submit button. When I press the submit button in Windows Safari, the computer will take about 8 seconds to START loading the page, then like 1 second or 2 seconds to load the page, taking around 9-10 seconds to load the page. While it is loading, the parent page which contained my form tag will be blank until the new page finished loading. Is there a way, via code or Safari settings, to minimise or even better, remove the 9-10 seconds? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you load that target page in a browser tab without sending a POST request? Do you have a similar problem when you click on a link that has `target="_blank"` (i.e. you also get a delay)? I also assume that you have set the `action` attribute in your form correctly?

Comment: No I don't have a problem when I use the <a href="#" target="_blank"></a> tag, it only happens when my form has a target=blank.